# Migrating Public Website Slowly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, migration

I am currently working on a website that was built on C# from the 2003 period using server controls, javascript without libraries like the modern age a lack of a data access layer and plenty of spaghetti code.

We have decide due to the sheer size of the web site we will have to migrate web pages peices at time.

The problem is we have links, navigation and menus that need to point from an old domain where the legacy pages are to the new domain where our new MVC 4, BootStrap and clean greenfield rewrites of these legacy pages are being created.  The problem is also that the new web pages will have links, navigation and menus that will have to point back to the old site as well.

I know I can create 302, I can use URL rewriting even.

My concern is that all developers will need to keep track of links both in the massive legacy website to the new website and update the urls manually.

Is there a simple way of migrating a website slowly?
Is there an approach I should research to handling this?
Should I stop snivling and just tell everyone on my team to keep track of the links as they go along and use something like wget on the legacy site to find all the links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a central repository for all the links, an XML file would do nicely, where both new and legacy sites would refer to get the URLs for the links.

Yes, you would need to change all links in both new and legacy to use this repository, but the upside is that once a page has been changed you can just change it's URL in the repository and all the links in both sites would now change.